# Is this sentence constructed correctly?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, construction

Is the second sentence constructed correctly? I read it several times and it seems that there's a comma missing or some discrepancy. Anyway I can't get the exact meaning of the part "has been sold to advertisers is another matter".

> I keep these emails partly because it’s my job to do so, but it seems that whether we’re paid to or not we can’t live without updates from our favourite social platforms. **Whether this illustrates a deep need to be loved or a deep paranoia that one of these emails will tell you that your shoe size *has been sold to advertisers is another matter*, but it’s interesting to see that, while social sites often send out more marketing emails than other sectors, we can’t bear the thought of missing them.** 
>   https://econsultancy.com/blog/64097-email-marketing-what-makes-people-unsubscribe/

Comment: One could argue to add or remove commas here and there, but I see nothing wrong with it as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Here's the structure:

> Whether this illustrates
>
> - a deep need to be loved
>
> or
>
> - a deep paranoia that one of these emails will tell you that your shoe size has been sold to advertisers
>
> is another matter,
>
> but
>
> it’s interesting to see that,
>
> - while social sites often send out more marketing emails than other sectors,
>
> we can’t bear the thought of missing them.

It's basically saying that regardless of whether it's motivated by a need for love or motivated by paranoia, "we" keep wanting to read "them". Here, "them" refers to "updates from our favourite social platforms" from the preceding sentence.

The part about the shoe size is a reference to people selling *information* to advertisers. In this case, that information is the shoe size. The ones interested in that information are presumably advertisers who are selling shoes.

Comment: Also note that sentence #1 (..that[,] whether .. not[,] we ..) has the same structure and also deserves commas.

Comment: The sentence would have been easier to parse had it had a comma after "loved".